# Estructura tablas de datos SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy tratando de crear una base de datos en SQL que contenga un campo con varias opciones (ENUM) relacionado con otro campo que también contenga varias opciones en función de lo seleccionado en el primer caso

Ejemplo -->

Tabla: gastos

Nombre del campo: categoría

Lista de valores posibles: 'vivienda', 'transporte', 'comercio'...

Entonces dentro del campo vivienda existirian varias opciones: 'alquiler', 'hipoteca', 'seguro'...

O lo que es lo mismo, si un usuario selecciona 'vivienda' automáticamente se relaciona con: 'alquiler', 'hipoteca', 'seguro'...

La única solución que veo es crear una tabla por cada categoría de gastos. ¿Existe otra forma?

Comment: Una tabla por cada categoria... eso no es para nada correcto... Tenes una tabla de categorias.. y una tabla de subcategorias.... Capaz si mostras exactamente que queres, entonces se te pueda ayudar mejor

Comment: Como te comenta gbianchi, lo que corresponde es definir correctamente tus entidades antes de pensar en la implementación. Al sesgarlo, terminas con un modelo mal hecho que te traerá problemas después. Una cosa es la categoría del gasto y otra, las opciones/subcategorías de cada categoría. Eso no es una tabla por categoría.

Comment: ¿Puede existir una subcategoría que dependa de otra subcategoría? Por ejemplo, en transporte puede ser 'renta de auto' y 'combustible'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que al final puedes simplificar todo sin usar ENUM, al final eso es mas para valores estáticos que no vas a relacionar.

La mejor opción desde mi punto de vista es crear 3 tablas y luego relacionarlas con querys. (no lo he ejecutado, posiblemente tenga algo mal)

```
CREATE TABLE gastos (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    category_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categoria(id)
);

CREATE TABLE categoria (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE opciones_categoria (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    category_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categoria(id)
);
```

Al final solo necesitas relacionar las tablas en la consulta para devolver los datos.

```
SELECT g.name as gasto, c.name as categoria, oc.name as tipo FROM gastos as g
    INNER JOIN categoria as c ON c.id=g.category_id
    INNER JOIN opciones_categoria as oc ON oc.category_id=c.id
;
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda